# Intellij IDEA cannot resolve 'andThen' functional interface method when referenced Function::andThen

Tags: java, intellij-idea, functional-programming, java-8

How can I get IntellijIDEA to find the 'andThen' method of the core java 8 'Function' interface when using the notation Funciton::andThen? I've tried many things unsuccessfully.

My intellijIDEA module is configured to java 8, the sdk used is the oracle java 8, I've invalidated the caches, and tried several other things, but still the editor marks and then as: "cannot resolve method 'andThen'".

I can launch and build this sample, so I think it's something to do with the static code analyzer. Maybe a bug?

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Meh {


    public static void main(String... args) {


        final List<Function<String, String>> fs = new ArrayList<>();
        fs.add(s -> s + "1");
        fs.add(s -> s + "2");

        final Function<String, String> f =
                fs.stream()
                        //copmiles from cli and project->make, but editor shows: Cannot resolve method 'andThen'
                        .reduce(Function::andThen)
                        .get();

        System.out.println(f.apply(""));//succesfully prints 12

        final Function<String,String> f2 = f.andThen(s-> s+"a");

        //succesfully prints 12a
        System.out.println(f2.apply(""));


    }

}
```

Something interesting is that when I reference f.andThen, the static code analyzer doesn't complain. It only happens when I reference Function::andThen.

This is not a problem when using eclipse. Or again, when compiling from the command line, or going to project -> make

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in IntelliJ 15.0.2, with 15.0.1 I could reproduce this error marker.

Quite some bugs which sound like your kind of problem are mentioned in the [release notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+15+143.869.1+Release+Notes), section "Java.Error Highlighting", e.g.:

- [IDEA-146604](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146604) (Bug) Valid code highlighted as error (Enum::compareTo)
- [IDEA-147873](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147873) (Bug) Good code marked red with lambdas/method references

Comment: 15.0.2 is not yet GA (release), right? I wasn't able to find it in regular downloads page:

 https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: @portenez You are absolutely right, sorry! I got the update information and didn't even realize that it is only in EAP ... But since it is a minor update I do hope, they release it soon - including the fixes for your issue!

Comment: I'll be on the lookout for the next version. In the mean time, there's a so-so workaround:

Create a lambda on the fly and then call andThen within the lambda. IDEA won't complain that way.

Comment: @portenez 15.0.2 seems to be released now, you can grab it at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: Yup, is not reproducible anymore. Thanks!